# Moving AJAX code to laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I found in the web tutorial about ajax, I tested code from this site 
http://tzachsolomon.blogspot.com/2013/02/ajax-first-example-based-on-new-boston.html
And it was working fine.

Now I want to move it to laravel, I know how to deal with blades and javascript, but I have no idea where to put php code (in controller?) and how set a route to this. I'm beginner with php/laravel/js , and I don't want to touch jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a route to the ajax request is same as that you do for the other laravel routs. Just define the controller and method in the routs file

> Route::get('/ajaxUrl', 'controllername@methodname');

In your controller same as you do for other controller methods define what to do with the post elements you get from the ajax